# Event for exiting the screen monitor (with WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf

I am writing a program that uses a WPF window. I use the next code to maximize the window:

```
   this.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;            
   this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;      
   this.Topmost = true;
```

When the window is maximized, I want to know if the mouse exits the border of my monitor so I can open a new window that offers some new controls (just like in BsPlayer: when the mouse exits the screen a window opens that gives you access to buttons like play, pause, stop etc.).
I tried to use this.MouseLeave, but no event appeared to be triggered when the window is maximized. After some tests I've discovered that the problem might be that when the my window is maximized, it is actually larger than the resolution of the monitor. On a basic example: if your monitor has a resolution of 1280 x 1024, the window has a dimension (according to this.Width and this.Height) of 1294 x 1038. So what should I do ? How should I approach the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle the Window's `MouseMove` event and check the mouse's position.

```
private void Window_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   //PrimaryScreenWidth - 1 to account for the cursor itself
   if (e.GetPosition(this).X >= SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth - 1 || e.GetPosition(this).X <= 1)
       MessageBox.Show("Edge hit");
}
```

If you're running multiple monitors, you could also handle the `MouseLeave` event to handle the case where the mouse has moved to the second monitor.

```
private void Window_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Edge hit");
}
```

Comment: Ok,  if (e.GetPosition(this).Y >= SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight - 1) was what I needed. Thank you very much !